# TortoiseGit side-by-side with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, git, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

I've been using TortoiseSVN for several years now, but am thinking of slowly changing to git, as I really like its branching and merging. I'm currently using git via the command line but am considering installing TortoiseGit. Has anyone had experience of using the two Tortoises side-by-side? Any known issues with this? I would really like not to screw up my SVN installation, as I will be using it for my existing projects.

Comment: I have installed both on my windows xp system and they work fine for me.

Comment: More specifically: do overlays work as expected? I can't see they can conflict in many other things.

Comment: @Alvaro Yes, that was one of my concerns - in my experience, anything that uses the icon cache is cause for concern!

Comment: It worked right away for me, and no icon problems detected. Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit, with "_TortoiseSVN 1.9.3, Build 27038 - 64 Bit_" already installed. I installed "_TortoiseGit 2.0.0.0 git version 2.6.1.windows.1_" on top of that.

Comment: OP did not accept any of the answers, but the consensus seems that both Tortoises can coexist happily without biting each other

Answer (score 10):

I've been using it for a couple of months now.  There are no issues that I've seen with them interacting and overlays work as expected.

I'm running the 64-bit versions on Win 7

Comment: worked out of the bag. I see my file status values etc ... never changed anything. granted there is some lag and they don't always update but they seem to work fine.  I'm running TortoiseGit 1.5.8.0 on top of git 17.3.1.msysgit.0 (Windows installer package)

Comment: Having TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit and only see overlays of the first installed client (TortoiseSVN). Also having OneDrive and DropBox installed. Removed DropBox overlays since it isn't very important to me - but still can't see TortoiseGit overlay icons ...

Answer (score 1):

The risk is that some of the icon overlays may not appear, especially if you have OneDrive or DropBox or some other app installed that decorates file icons. These are governed by the max allowed entries in the Windows Registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer \ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers. The max appears to be 15.
[See this article in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411336/shelliconoverlayidentifiers-why-so-few)

However, TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit appear to share the same named overlays, so there does not appear to be a risk of some appearing, and others not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer my own question, I just bit the bullet and installed Tortoise Git and everything seems to be working with no problems. The icon overlays show up as expected with both git and svn. This is on Win2K.

Answer (score 0):

I "bit the bullet" yesterday, also on 64 Win 7 and i'm darned if I can coax the Git icon overlays to work, Svn has continued to work flawlessly though. Everything else Git seems to be working though, as far as I've trialled so far anyhow.