# Using Git and Subversion in parallel (Tortoise)

Tags: git, tortoisesvn, git-svn, tortoisegit

At work we use Subversion, I often use it with Tortoise.  I want to start to use Git for non-official changes.

One problem is we seem to use both SVN Git and Tortoise Git on the same directories.

What would be the appropriate Git software to install? How to work? What should I do about the conflict between the Tortoises?  I know you can quickly enable/disable features with registry-scripts, but that would be machine-wide.

I plan to move to git svn, and I somestimes use Visual Studio (I could use VS for Git only)

Comment: Do you really have one working copy used with two kinds of version control systems? Otherwise, if you just use separate directories there should not be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no "conflicts" betweeen TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit. They can both share the icon overlay.

http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2010/4/1/27119

Related question:  [Tortoise Git side-by-side with Tortoise SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461087/tortoise-git-side-by-side-with-tortoise-svn)

TortoiseGit is excellent for initial move to Git, and it supports git-svn related commands as well. And Git is at its best in the command line anyway, so if TortoiseGit is not what you want, I would say, just use the cli.